# How to use data from csv file in python?

Tags: python, csv

My current `gradesheetscores.csv` file looks like this

```
Name ,Score 
Alice ,56
Jack,90
Naima,56
Marcus,87
Lizzy,34
Yasmin,20
TOP,100
Hannah,78
Rosa,32
Jaesuk,100
```

I want to use the scores only for my program to get average and other stuff (which I can do)I only need to know - How do I select only these data ? I'm a beginner (2 weeks old) so don't be harsh please.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: Show us what you have tried in Python so far. The `csv` module has [some nice examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#examples).

Answer (score 2):

you can use csv package

```
import csv
data_file = open('your_file.csv', 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(data_file)
column = {}
headers = reader.next()
for h in headers:
    column[h] = []
for row in reader:
    for h, v in zip(headers, row):
        column[h].append(v)
score = column['Score']
```

now score variable contains your score values